# Is there a word for when you grab somebody, spin them around, and throw them?

Tags: terminology

I've seen a move like this in games like Tekken and Yakuza, typically by characters with unrefined fighting mastery. Below are links showcasing the move in question in both Tekken 7 and Yakuza Kiwami 2, respectively.

[Tekken](https://youtu.be/8xfBKuDUJbY?t=356)

[Yakuza](https://youtu.be/4eY1_mGt4WI?t=1016)

I'm curious as to whether or not there is an official or a colloquial term for this kind of barroom-brawl-style fighting move. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assult / battery?

Comment: Dunno, but maybe you could call it a hammer throw. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=P6UwokP8BEg

Comment: @Jim If I had to be completely honest, "hammer throw" is probably one of the best names for a fighting move I've ever heard. After hearing hammer throw, I don't think I want to know the actual name of this move anymore because I know it will not top a name like hammer throw. Not only does it sound awesome, it also fits extremely well with the move in question. I mean, damn. That's a great name for it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the *combined* move would be as a fighting technique.

It starts of with what I'd describe, in pair figure skating, as a [**pair spin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_skating_spins).

[image: pair spin]

It would then be followed by one person being thrown after momentum had built up. So, possibly just **spin and throw**.

---

The act of building up something's momentum and then releasing it in a redirected trajectory (sometimes due to an actual spin) is also described as a [**slingshot**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slingshot):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 a** : a maneuver in auto racing in which a drafting car accelerates past the car in front by taking advantage of reserve power
> **b** : a dragster in which the driver sits behind the rear wheels

Although the definition wouldn't seem to apply (in fact, I've always thought of that maneuver as *drafting*), the word is used in Merriam-Webster's first example sentence to describe principles of centrifugal (or spinning) force:

> // In fact, this tortuous trajectory necessitated gravity *slingshots* around Earth, Venus, Earth, and finally Earth again before moving toward the outer Solar System.
> // — Eric Berger, Ars Technica, "A congressman’s loss clouds the future of two demanding missions to Europa," 3 Dec. 2018

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slingshot) has a more directly relevant definition of this sense of the word:

> *[mass noun, often as modifier]* The effect of the gravitational pull of a celestial object in accelerating and changing the course of another object or a spacecraft.
>
> ‘stars passing near a black hole might be ejected by a gravitational slingshot effect’